# Not able to connect to Bluetooth server and WiFi at same time

Tags: android, sockets, connection, android-wifi, android-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device through which user can take photos. After taking the photos Bluetooth device hosts all the images on its own HTTP server (10.0.0.1), so that other devices can connect to server using Bluetooth and access photos from server using REST APIs which are exposed by server.

**Steps to connect to Bluetooth device (Server)**

1. Go to Setting, enable Bluetooth
2. Select Bluetooth device
3. Bluetooth device setting ("Paired Bluetooth device")
4. Select check box for Internet access.

Through this i am able to access Bluetooth server but my WiFi automatically gets disabled and I am not able to access internet.

If i uncheck "Internet access" check box in "Paired Bluetooth device setting" then I am able to connect to WiFi for internet access.

Is it possible to have both WiFi internet as well as Bluetooth internet at the same time? So that my app can connect to Bluetooth device to get the data (images) using REST APIs and post to remote server using WiFi.

I am using Nexus 7 tab for development which is running on Android 4.4.4.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

***1. ...so that other devices can connect to server using Bluetooth and access photos from server using REST APIs which are exposed by server***
If the photos are on the server, devices can connect to it using wifi/internet also..right? To access the APIs and get the photos..
Why do you want other devices to connect to server ***using bluetooth*** to access photos from server using REST APIs

***2. Is it possible to have both WiFi internet as well as Bluetooth internet at the same time?***
Leave aside *Bluetooth internet*, there have been some issues related to Bluetooth and Wifi, even more with Bluetooth Low Energy and Wifi, many have been device specific.

Regarding what you are facing, there are issues on *Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker* and other blogs also;

[Issue 39995](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39995)
[Issue 41631](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41631)

[Nexus 5, Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 (2013) Android 4.4 Bluetooth Issues](http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/533189/20140107/nexus-5-7-android-4-kitkat.htm#.U8dp_vmSwrE)
[Although i haven't faced that issue in Nexus 5]

I have seen the same in MotoG also, turning on Bluetooth weakens the Wifi functionality.

In your case, considering nothing can be done with the device and its hardware,
you can check with the connections whether it happens intermittently, try to connect or send the request to server a couple of times.

***3. ...app can connect to Bluetooth device to get the data (images) using REST APIs***
If it can "connect" to the Bluetooth device, i suggest you try and get the images on the established connection rather than REST APIs. *Simultaneous internet access through two different sources doesn't happen, even with the 3G and wifi* :)
Just out of curiosity, when you are *connected* to the Bluetooth device, why do you want to add the necessity of internet to get the data?

*Another approach, gets ugly but would work:* Can you get the data that you need and ask the user to switch off the bluetooth so you can send the data..which you might need only on certain devices, if you separately get the data from the established bluetooth connection only

Comment: 1. Bluetooth device which we are using is from third party vendor and it can only work as a Bluetooth server (It's a portable device) and it does not have the functionality to connect using WiFi or getting image directly from device.
2. Once Bluetooth is disabled then used need to go to setting and enable it again. So I think android OS has to fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, for some devices, the issue remains as it is. For 2., from what i have seen, once bluetooth is disabled, the Wifi connection, range, signal shoots up and internet works as normal.

Comment: For 2 Yes its happening same way in Nexus 7. Once you disable Bluetooth WiFi shoots up with full power and we are able to connect to internet. For now we are planning to have a ugly approach to show msg to user to enable Bluetooth and once download is completed we will request user to disable it. We still have sometime before release so we will try to get the fix for this problem. We don't have to request user for enabling and disabling it again and again.

Comment: with the ugly approach, work on an interactive, easy-on-the-eye ui